# 'Expansion' shortcuts (aka SQL templates?) in DBeaver

Tags: toad, dbeaver

I use TOAD for oracle and been trying to get into DBeaver.
I was curious if DBeaver offers user ability to create custom shortcuts that 'expand'.
A simple example would be typing 'selll' expands to  'select * FROM '.
I use a ton of these 'expansions' for long table/column names and shortcuts like above.
I use this feature alot in TOAD and was hoping to have an equivalent in DBeaver.
Thanks in advance!
Note: another free tool SQL Developer seems to have this:  [Shortcut for Queries in SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535976/shortcut-for-queries-in-sql-developer)
Hopefully DBeaver has the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, DBeaver has this useful feature also called Templates. It is a standard Eclipse model engine. It has some templates and you can create your own using a few variables.

Click [here](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/SQL-Templates) to check it out.

> To see available templates, press Ctrl+Alt+SPACE or right-click the line in the script pane and click SQL Template on the context menu. A box with a list of available templates appears:
>
> [image: A box with a list of available templates appears]
>
> To apply a template, in the SQL Editor, in the script pane:
>
> - Type the template name and press Tab
> - Right-click the line where you want to insert a template expression, click SQL Template on the context menu, and then, in the list of templates, double-click the required template name.
>   The template SQL statement appears in the script.
>
> To edit/add/remove templates, click Configure () in the bottom toolbar, then click Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Templates.

Comment: Links based answers are not considered right (the link could become orphan at any time). You should add the useful info of the linked page. There is a lot of discussion on Meta about this topic https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144566/new-policy-on-link-only-answers